# Ctrl+Shift+u does not work on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, unicode

I have installed Kubuntu 18.04 and want to input unicode characters, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> combo does not work. I also try to install `ibus` using `sudo apt install ibus ibus-gtk ibus-qt4 ibus m17n`, then call ibus-setup, but this combo key does not work now although it works on Kubuntu 16.04.

when I attempt to change input method to "other unicode(m17n)", it fails and gives

```
(ibus-daemon:1738): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:13:26.272: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
```

How I can input unicode on Kubuntu 18.04 by any other Methods?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried it again, it doesn't work in konsole, kate,and other applications, I installed gnome-terminal, it works correctly in gnome-terminal.